# Custom Print Preview -- Design Choice

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I need to implement a custom print preview screen for one of the pages in my MVC web project. I was just wondering what some of the recommended ways of doing it are. Basically, we have a dropdown menu with a bunch of different options-- each one displays a different statistical report under the dropdown menu. For the print preview, I only want to preview the report, not the whole page.

Should I simply take the html and cut off the stuff I don't want, and re-render it? Or create some kind of other document, XPS maybe, and display it as that? Alternate CSS maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that anyone is probably interested, but I ended up just using the HTML from the original page and disabling/restyling all of the links and stuff, and hid unnecessary elements via javascript.